# Does MS Word have an "unsaved changes" indicator?

Tags: microsoft-word

When I have made changes to a document that I haven't yet saved, most text editors I've used have an indicator somewhere in the interface to that effect. E.g. Notepad++ shows an asterisk in the beginning of the window title. Does MS Word have something like that?

*MS Word version: 2010*

Answer (score 2):

One way to know if a document has unsaved changes is by looking at the `redo` button.

[image]

This icon/button dims out if the file has no changes since it was last saved.

Comment: Good as quick hint but I found it is not always reliable. I can create the status where Redo is active while the document is saved.

Comment: Just wondering how did you make it active when the document is saved?

Comment: Simply: (1) Close currently open document. (2) Now the Redo is active either on remaining open document (saved or unsaved) OR even after you open existing or create new document. In all cases it says "Repeat Doc Close". Perhaps there are other commands where this can be achieved, too.

Comment: Ok then it's ideal if only single instance is opened may be.

Answer (score 1):

### Reliable method: asking Word directly.

Let's get saved status directly from place where it is stored.
Create custom macro with single command:

```
MsgBox "Saved: " & ActiveDocument.Saved
```

When you run it (using toolbar icon or keyboard shortcut), it will show you the status right away.

Answer (score 0):

Directly in the title bar? This is not a thing Microsoft puts in its products likely. But if you open the Start screen (Ribbon > File; or `ALT` + `F`), note the field `Last Modified` on the right, under `Related dates`; it's a date stamp that updates whenever you save the document.

[image]